# how can I search such tree structure by value in typescript without getting maximum stack call exceeded

Tags: javascript, typescript

how can I search such tree structure by value in typescript without getting maximum stack call exceeded.
I am trying to search an expandable tree using typescript , I will attach the code I am trying down below

```
tree= [
    {
        "size": -1320,
        "offset": 0,
        "value": "E",
        "subNodes": [
            {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"
            },
            {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"
            },
            {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"
            }
        ],
{
        "size": -1320,
        "offset": 0,
        "value": "E",
        "subNodes": [
            {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"
            },
            {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D",
               "subNodes": [
                {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"
               },
               {
                "size": 48,
                "offset": 0,
                "value": "D"]
            }]]
```

and I am getting maximum call stack reached! I am not sure why , is it due to the recursive call of the function? is it possible to search with just letters of the value ?
here is my code :

```
 searchTree(protcolTree: Array<SessionTree>, searchString: string): Array<SessionTree> {
        if (this.protocolTree[0].value === searchString) {
            this.protocolTree = protcolTree;
        } else if (this.protocolTree.length) {
            let result: Array<SessionTree> = null;
            for (let i = 0; result === null && i < this.protocolTree.length; i++) {
                result = this.searchTree(this.protocolTree[i].subNodes, searchString);
            }
            this.protocolTree = result;
            return result;
        }
        return this.protocolTree;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  searchTreeNodes(tree: Array<SessionTree>, searchString: string): void {
        this.protocolTree.filter(node => node.value === searchString);
    }
```